# Inform the child component that it is a part of the parent component's Angular FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, components, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormGroup` that reference some of its field to another component that makes it its child. However, I am getting this error whenever I am on the `rendering` stage of the child

```
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup...
```

This is a generic error when you include a `formControlName` property on a field outside the `FormGroup`. I have make sure that the parent rendered first the FormGroup before its child, and by right, that's the default behaviour.

Parent HTML is something like this.

```
<form [formGroup]="form.formGroup" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(formDirective)">
      <input matInput formControlName="form.mainInputControl" placeholder="This one doesn't have a problem" type="text">
      <child-component [details]="form.detailsForChild"></child-component>
</form>
```

Child HTML is something like this

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="detailsForChild.checkBoxControl"></mat-checkbox>
```

PS: That's not real variable name, I just do it so it will be intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, contrary to what I had assumed, the Child and Parent Components cannot be mixed up during runtime.

Therefore, I had to provide the precise `FormGroup` to the child and bind it to the element one level higher where the "formControlName" is defined.

So from the example:

`Parent`

```
<form [formGroup]="form.formGroup" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(formDirective)">
      <input matInput formControlName="form.mainInputControl" placeholder="This one doesn't have a problem" type="text">
      <child-component [details]="form.detailsForChild" [parentForm]="form.formGroup"></child-component>
</form>
```

Child

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="detailsForChild.checkBoxControl"></mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

Reference: [Here](https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add formControlName

```js
<child-component formControlName="form.detailsForChild"></child-component>
```

You need to write the below code in child component

```js
import {ControlContainer, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  // Ensure we either have a [formControl] or [formControlName] with our child-component
  selector: '[formControl] child-component,[formControlName] child-component',
  templateUrl: './address-editor.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public checkBoxControl: FormControl;

  // Let Angular inject the control container
  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Set our addressFormGroup property to the parent control
    // (i.e. FormGroup) that was passed to us, so that our
    // view can data bind to it
    this.checkBoxControl = this.controlContainer.control;
  }
}
```

```html
//Child component code
<mat-checkbox formControlName="checkBoxControl"></mat-checkbox>
```

[For more info click on the link](https://mrpmorris.blogspot.com/2017/08/angular-composite-controls-formgroup-formgroupname-reactiveforms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add the formGroup in child component also

Parent

```
<form [formGroup]="form.formGroup" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(formDirective)">
      <input matInput formControlName="form.mainInputControl" placeholder="This one doesn't have a problem" type="text">
      <child-component [parentFormGroup]="form.formGroup" [details]="form.detailsForChild"></child-component>
</form>
```

Child

```
<div [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="detailsForChild.checkBoxControl"></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```